# Defining hasMany IDs as nullable in Grails 3

Tags: sql, hibernate, grails, grails-orm, grails3

I have a Grails 2 app, where one domain object uses this line:

```
static hasMany = [masters: AssetType, shortforms: AssetType, mezzanines: AssetType, captions: AssetType, artwork: AssetType, ancillary: AssetType]
```

The resulting bridge table has 7 columns and all of them are nullable,  and the table itself is sparsely populated, with most rows just having values in 2/7 columns.

Now, I am working on migrating to Grails 3. 
The Grails 3 version of the app has the exact same domain class definition, but the resulting table only has AssetType_ID as nullable.

I get this error when trying to populate that table with some null values:

> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: NULL not allowed for column "AEPARTNER_PACKAGE_ANCILLARY_ID"; SQL statement:
>               insert into aepartner_package_asset_type (aepartner_package_artwork_id, asset_type_id) values (?, ?) [23502-197]

Adding the following code to the domain class' "constraints" did not help.

```
ancillary nullable: true
```

NOTE: I used H2 web client to view the table data and table definitions including the IS_NULLABLE field.

**How can I set those columns/fields to be nullable in Grails 3?**

Data source definitions:

```
dataSource:
    pooled: true
    jmxExport: true
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    username: sa
    password: ''

environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: create-drop
            url: jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
            grails.dbconsole.enabled: true
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd switch to doc-oriented DB here...

Comment: Those are not the only domain objects in the app, but thank you - it's an interesting idea.

Comment: The fields you are talking about should be nullable in GORM, but ddl-ed into your DB (H2?) as not-nullable. How is your data-source defined?

Comment: btw are those many-to-ones or many-to-manys?

Comment: I added dataSource definition to the question.

Comment: I only care for one-to-many relationship. That being said there is no unique relationship to AssetTypes objects, they can be referenced by multiple other objects.

Comment: have you defined all those fields as `nullable`? The exception thrown complains about `AEPARTNER_PACKAGE_ANCILLARY_ID` being nullable, but I don't see it in he insert statement's columns list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182384/discussion-between-daniil-shevelev-and-injecteer).